# Finding intersections of words in dataframe strings - whole words only

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Below is a sample dataframe, and for every Bus # description I would like to find all other Bus #s with descriptions that have at least one of the same words.

```
Bus #                  DESCRIPTION

Bus1                   RICE MILLS MANUFACTURER 
Bus2                   LICORICE CANDY RETAIL
Bus3                   LICORICE CANDY WHOLESALE
Bus4                   RICE RETAIL
```

For example, the output for:

```
RICE MILLS MANUFACTURER would be "RICE RETAIL"
LICORICE CANDY RETAIL would be "RICE RETAIL" "LICORICE CANDY WHOLESALE"
LICORICE CANDY WHOLESALE would be "LICORICE CANDY RETAIL"
RICE RETAIL would be: "RICE MILLS MANUFACTURER" "LICORICE CANDY RETAIL"
```

The following code almost does this correctly.

```
df[df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains(df['DESCRIPTION'][0].split()[0])]
df[df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains(df['DESCRIPTION'][0].split()[1])]
df[df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains(df['DESCRIPTION'][0].split()[2])]
df[df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains(df['DESCRIPTION'][1].split()[0])]
df[df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains(df['DESCRIPTION'][1].split()[1])]
df[df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains(df['DESCRIPTION'][1].split()[2])]
df[df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains(df['DESCRIPTION'][2].split()[0])]
df[df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains(df['DESCRIPTION'][2].split()[1])]
df[df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains(df['DESCRIPTION'][2].split()[2])]
df[df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains(df['DESCRIPTION'][3].split()[0])]
df[df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains(df['DESCRIPTION'][3].split()[1])]
```

The problem is the word "rice" is in "licorice" so the output for RICE MILLS MANUFACTURER includes "LICORICE RETAIL." I don't want that.

Comment: What output structure do you want? Lists? Series? Dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

This is still O(n^2), however, it is highly vectorized.

```
# get values of DESCRIPTION
s = df.DESCRIPTION.values.astype(str)

# parse strings and turn into sets
sets = np.array([set(l) for l in np.core.defchararray.split(s).tolist()])

# get upper triangle indices for all combinations of DESCRIPTION
r, c = np.triu_indices(len(sets), 1)

# use set operations to replicate intersection
i = sets[r] - sets[c] < sets[r]

# grab indices where intersections happen
r, c = r[i], c[i]
r, c = np.append(r, c), np.append(c, r)
```

## results

```
df.DESCRIPTION.iloc[c].groupby(r).apply(list)

0                                       [RICE RETAIL]
1             [LICORICE CANDY WHOLESALE, RICE RETAIL]
2                             [LICORICE CANDY RETAIL]
3    [RICE MILLS MANUFACTURER, LICORICE CANDY RETAIL]
Name: DESCRIPTION, dtype: object
```

## To compare timings

```
# build truth matrix
t = np.empty((s.size, s.size), dtype=np.bool)
t.fill(False)

t[r, c] = True

pd.DataFrame(t, df.index, df.index)

       0      1      2      3
0  False  False  False   True
1  False  False   True   True
2  False   True  False  False
3   True   True  False  False
```

---

***timing***

[image]

Comment: I want the output for Rice Retail to not include Licorice Candy Retail. Other than that this is the right output. I figured out a solution that does it right but the method probably isn't as fast as yours.

Answer (score 1):

```
def match_word(ref_row,series):
    """
    --inputs
    ref_row (str): this is the string of reference
    series (pandas.series): this a series containing all other strings you want to cross-check
    --outputs:
    series (pandas.series): this will be a series of booleans
    """
    #convert ref_row into a set of strings. Use strip to remove whitespaces before and after the initial string
    ref_row = set(ref_row.strip().split(' '))
    #convert strings into set of strings 
    series = series.apply(lambda x:set(x.strip().split(' ')))
    #now cross check each row with the reference row.
    #find the size (number of words) of the intersection
    series = series.apply(lambda x:len(list(x.intersection(ref_row))))
    #if the size of the intersection set is greater than zero. Then there is a common word between ref_row and all the series
    series = series>0
    return series
```

Now, you can call the above function as follow:

```
df['Description'].apply(lambda x:match_word(x,df['Description']))
```

Please note that this is not the best optimized algorithm, but it's the quick and dirty approach. This is a O(n2).